# Python: Intersecting multiple List columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

i have 3 Lists:

```
a = [[abc, def, ghd], [...], ...]
b = [[abc, olnaf, kjbdsa], [...], ...]
c = [[abc, aeufga, älaga], [...], ...]
```

how do i find the intersecting Elements based on the first column (e.g. abc)?

I want to get a new List with the items of all three lists that share e.g.  the `'abc'` entry.

Greetings

Chris

Comment: you mean based on `abc` you want to show which of the sublists in `a`, `b` and `c` contain this element?

Comment: Please show us what you tried, and what you are expecting as a result from a specific input...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your repliey. I did it finally with a Pandas Dataframe and an inner join on the columns of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the occurences of strings in the first item in first column?

```
column = 0

a = [["abc", "def", "ghd"], [], []]
b = [["abc", "olnaf", "kjbdsa"], [], []]
c = [["abc", "aeufga", "älaga"], [], []]

from collections import Counter
Counter([i[0] for i in list(zip(a,b,c))[column]])
```

Prints

```
Counter({'abc': 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly find intersections using sets

```
a = [["abc", "def", "ghd"], ["1", "2", "3"]]
b = [["abc", "olnaf", "kjbdsa"], []]
c = [["abc", "aeufga", "älaga"], ["1", "2"]]

for i, (a, b, c) in enumerate(zip(a, b, c)):
    print("Index", i)
    print("  a & b:", set(a) & set(b))
    print("  b & c:", set(b) & set(c))
    print("  a & c:", set(a) & set(c))
```

Output

```
Index 0
  a & b: {'abc'}
  b & c: {'abc'}
  a & c: {'abc'}
Index 1
  a & b: set()
  b & c: set()
  a & c: {'2', '1'}
```